# Breakline after matching pattern with awk

Tags: awk

I have this kind of file

```
A 1,2,3,4
B 1
C 1,2
```

I would like to get with awk this output :

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 1 
C 1 
C 2
C 3
```

tried code:

```
sed 's/,/\n&/g' file
```

Any idea with awk?

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Actually, I tried with    sed 's/,/\n&/g'    , but I didn't get what I want ..

Comment: Sure, thank you for showing your efforts, please do add them in your question in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following, using multiple field separator concept, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** splitting 2nd field value.

```
awk '{num=split($2,arr,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print $1,arr[i]}}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/,ORS $1 OFS)}1' file
```

Output:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 1
C 1
C 2
```

And if you really want THAT output from THAT input, you need to add `END{print "C 3"}` in the end...

**Edit** Please see @EdMorton's comment for a pitfall.

Comment: Just be aware that'd fail if `$1` contained `&`.